# How to setup and switch between two Github accounts in Windows based on folders?

Tags: git

I am using a **Windows** machine provided by my organization.For the office-related work, I use a Github business account provided by my organization. I want to do some personal projects where I need to use my personal Github account. How can I seamlessly switch between the two.
I have done a lot of search and I got answers regarding how to setup SSH key generation for Github accounts. But I am stuck at the step of cloning the repository. I want to use my personal Github account id to clone this repository and push the code to my personal branch

Comment: Do you mean that you have two _Github_ accounts? Note that git and Github are not the same thing, so you will likely confuse yourself and others if you don't distinguish them clearly.

Comment: Use multiple ssh keys and configure them to use different git accounts. https://medium.com/@xiaolishen/use-multiple-ssh-keys-for-different-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer-7d7103ca8693

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, I have two Github accounts. I have edited the question for clarity. Thanks